# Famo.us functions in vanilla js? (Surface / StateModifier / Transitionable / Transform)

Tags: javascript, css, material-design, famous-angular

I'd like to reproduce this ripple-on-click effect:

http://jsfiddle.net/cjalatorre/zr2m5d88/

The fiddle is an extension from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25561577/3554602) answer:

> I decided to go with a CSS radial gradient in the button's background-image. I'm centering the ripple (the gradient's circle) at the touch/mouse point. I extended the Surface module in order to hook into the render cycle.
>
> There are two Transitionables, one for the diameter of the gradient and one for gradient opacity. Both of these are reset after the interaction. When the user clicks on a button, the Surface stores the X and Y offset and then transitions the gradient diameter to its max value. When the user releases the button, it transitions the gradient opacity to 0.
>
> The render cycle is constantly setting the background-image to a radial gradient with the circle at the X and Y offset, and getting the opacity and gradient diameter from the two Transitionables.

These famo.us modules are used:

```
var Engine = require('famous/core/Engine');
var Surface = require('famous/core/Surface');
var Timer = require('famous/utilities/Timer');
var StateModifier = require('famous/modifiers/StateModifier');
var Transform = require('famous/core/Transform');
var Transitionable = require('famous/transitions/Transitionable');
```

I'm not familiar with famo.us, so before I try and rewrite this, are there any obvious equivalent vanilla functions / gotchas?

Comment: can you explain the effect a bit? I do not see any obvious effects in the jsfiddle.

Comment: @Cort3z the ripple effect when clicking on a button. detail added.

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly ? Is implementing the effect your goal ? if so, it has nothing to do with famo.us.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at https://github.com/fians/Waves
You have the same effect, in JS, CSS, SASS, LESS...

Comment: thanks, I went for something similar / a little simpler: 
http://www.cssscript.com/material-design-click-ripple-effect-vanilla-javascript-material-touch/